# How to set program name?

Tags: configuration, webassembly, emcc, emsdk

How to set program name/argument 0 (`argv[0]`) with `emcc`? For example, `emcc hello.c -o hello.html` with `--set-name main`*.

**This is not the same as setting `Module.arguments`** (which changes arguments 1 and up, I want argument 0).

- in auto-generated `hello.js`, there is `var thisProgram="./this.program"`. Changing directly gives `Uncaught TypeError: str.charCodeAt is not a function`
- using `Module["thisProgram"]="./main";` in `--pre-js` gives `Uncaught TypeError: str.charCodeAt is not a function`

This is for web (with `.html`), so renaming `hello.js` to `main.js` does not work (it is still `./this.program`).

---

- `main` is just a placeholder. It will be something other than the default `./this.program`.